# LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Install

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, linker-errors

I am not very proficient in C++, and am getting a linking problem that I am not quite sure how to resolve. I have a solution that builds fine when in x64 mode, but gives a linking error in x86 mode.

I have confirmed that the project is configured to build as Win32, and Platform Toolset is set to v90.

The last few lines from the linker log before the error are as follows:

```
...
1>        Found "long __stdcall AfxDllCanUnloadNow(void)" (?AfxDllCanUnloadNow@@YGJXZ)
1>          Referenced in mfcs90.lib(oleexp.obj)
1>          Loaded mfc90.lib(mfc90.dll)
1>        Found "public: __thiscall CDynLinkLibrary::CDynLinkLibrary(struct HINSTANCE__ *,struct HINSTANCE__ *)" (??0CDynLinkLibrary@@QAE@PAUHINSTANCE__@@0@Z)
1>          Referenced in mfcs90.lib(dllmodulx.obj)
1>          Loaded mfc90.lib(mfc90.dll)
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\mfcs90.lib:
1>        Found __pRawDllMain
1>          Referenced in msvcrt.lib(crtdll.obj)
1>          Loaded mfcs90.lib(rawdllmainproxy.obj)
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\msvcrt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\user32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\msimg32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\comctl32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\shlwapi.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\msvcprt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\mapi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\lib\Ole32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\atls.lib:
1>  
1>  Finished searching libraries
1>  
1>  Generating .exp file
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Install
1>Release\app.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I have been doing wrong. I have found many similar issues, but the solutions don't seem to apply. Sorry for such a simple question.

Comment: Should be caused by linking the wrong version of libs, but I don't know which one. You can use link options to show the whole information in the link process to track it down, how to do it, please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx